how osgi code like "FrameworkUtil.getBundle" run in tomcat?
we have an application run on liberty ,but now our customer ask us to run on tomcat ,
so we  run osgi app on tomcat ,
now ,we find there is code like :
 BundleContext bc = null;
             bc = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(IdentityAssertionLoginModule.class).getBundleContext();

in one jar met problem ,and bc return null .
why ?
and we find  as similar issue (FrameworkUtil.getBundle returns me NULL always)
but can anyone tell us how to fix it ?
thank you @Neil Bartlett , @arsenal

FrameworkUtil.getBundle() method check if the classloader of the given class implements org.osgi.framework.BundleReference.
If it does (when running in proper bundle within proper OSGi runtime), this interface allows to obtain an org.osgi.framework.Bundle for this class (because in OSGi, each bundle revision/wiring has its own classloader) from its OSGi class loader.
In Tomcat, the class loader of the class is not a BundleReference, so you're getting null.
In general - Tomcat is not an OSGi runtime (it's an implementation of JakartaEE Servlet specification) and it's not possible to deploy/run OSGi bundles there.

and how to change osgi bundle code for  run on tomcat ?thank you

You simply can't... you have to prepare proper JakartaEE WAR application.

thank you for your kindly reply,we want to change code "FrameworkUtil.getBundle(IdentityAssertionLoginModule.class).getBundleContext();" for run in tomcat ,but we are not familar with osgi ,can you kindly geiv us some advice ?

There's no advice here... If you're responsible for migrating an OSGi application to Tomcat (JakartaEE Web server), then you need much more planning, prototyping and discussion than simple StackOverflow answer. You need to re-architecture your application.
